# UITextView does not fit NSTextContainer exactly

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring, nstextcontainer

I just created a custom method using a `TextKit` stack but am confused by what appears to be a difference between the size of `NSTextContainer` and the `NSTextView` frame size. The text has a white border and I’d like to know how to get rid of it (*see update*). The area following the last character is also white. I’ve set an attribute for `backgroundColor` using a range that matches the length of the string but so far I have not found a way to apply this attribute to the entire area.

I tried various combinations of settings for `NSTextContainer` and the text frame of `UITextView`. The following statements get closest to the desired result but the white border is still there.

```
    // A
    textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:textFrame.size];

    // D 
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textFrame textContainer: textContainer];
```

[image]

I worked through tutorials on `TextKit` [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial) and [here](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/getting-to-know-textkit/) and searched through Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/ArbitraryTextPath.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001807-CJBGBIBB) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Concepts/LayoutManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001805-BBCFEBHA) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextSystemArchitecture/ArchitectureOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH7-SW4). I also checked the [closest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21665578/2348597) and yes, my `appDelegate` has

```
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

---

**Update**

The white border has been eliminated following the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18987810/1801544) (*thanks Larme*)

[image]

The following statements were added to `textView` at the end of the method

```
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
```

---

In case it’s relevant, the app was started in iOS 4. It now runs iOS 11 using Xcode Version 9.2. It already uses `textView` and `TextKit` is now being considered (reluctantly) as a way to address a number of requests from app testers. So any pointer that might help explain and fix this problem would be welcome.

Thanks in anticipation.

Here is the code for the method. `helpMessage` is read from an Array (*not shown*).

```
    -(id)formatHelpText:(NSString*)helpMessage
{
    float sideMargin   = 5;
    float topMargin    = 72;

    CGFloat textWidth  = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - (sideMargin * 2);
    CGFloat textHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - (topMargin * 2);
    CGRect  textFrame  = CGRectMake(sideMargin, topMargin, textWidth, textHeight); // used for A & D


    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:helpMessage];

// define paragraph attributes

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [style setLineSpacing:1.5];
    [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

// use attributedText to define character attributes

    float spacing        = 0.0f;
    float baselineOffSet = 1.0f;

    [attributedText setAttributes:@{
                                NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody],
                                NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:baselineOffSet],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                NSBackgroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor grayColor],
                                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,
                                NSKernAttributeName:@(spacing)
                                }
                        range:range];


// TextKit - non-view

    NSTextStorage *textStorage;
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager;
    NSTextContainer *textContainer;

    textStorage   = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedText];
    layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] init];

    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];


// A
    textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:textFrame.size];
// B 
//    textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size];   
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];


// C
//    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds textContainer: textContainer];
// D 
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textFrame textContainer: textContainer];


// update

    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;

    return textView;
}
```

Comment: Add this `textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;` and `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;` on your current code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18987810/1801544 ?

Comment: Larme, the white border is gone. Thanks. See update.

Comment: Is there still an issue?

Comment: tried to get rid of the jagged last line using CGSize containerSize = CGSizeMake(textFrame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:containerSize];

Comment: also extended the background by adding "\r" to the string array - e.g.  ".....deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r"]," - but that's pretty crappy way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Both problems are now solved. The white border was removed using `UIEdgeInsetsZero` to clear the default setting and `textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0` (*thanks, Larme*). I hid the unhighlighted part of the last line of `UITextView` by removing background colour as a character attribute and defining it instead as a property of `textView.` `sizeToFit` is added to minimise the number of lines in `textView`. Here is the final code

```
#import "HelpTextView.h"

@implementation HelpTextView

-(id)formatHelpText:(NSString*)helpMessage
{
    float sideMargin   = 5;
    float topMargin    = 72;

    CGFloat textWidth  = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - (sideMargin * 2);
    CGFloat textHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - (topMargin * 2);
    CGRect  textFrame  = CGRectMake(sideMargin, topMargin, textWidth, textHeight);

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:helpMessage];

    // define paragraph attributes

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [style setLineSpacing:0.5];
    [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

    float spacing = 0.0f;
    float baselineOffSet = 1.0f;
    NSRange range = (NSRange){0,[attributedText length]};

    // use attributedText to define character attributes

    [attributedText setAttributes:@{
                                NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody],
                                NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:baselineOffSet],
                                NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],
                                NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style,
                                NSKernAttributeName:@(spacing)
                                }
                        range:range];

    NSTextStorage* textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedText];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    CGSize containerSize = CGSizeMake(textFrame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:containerSize];

    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: textFrame textContainer: textContainer];
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    textView.editable = NO;
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [textView sizeToFit];

    return textView;
}
```